# painting the widget on calling slot

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I want to paint a circle with user provided color and keep a line edit adjustment on it on horizontal alignment.

Used painter function call on slot, but its not working

```
#include <QPainter>
#include "cascadeColorHighlightWidget.h"

CascadeColorHighlightWidget::CascadeColorHighlightWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::Widget);
    setAttribute( Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true );
    setFixedSize(187,164);
    setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
}

void CascadeColorHighlightWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);

    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::TextAntialiasing);
    QRectF contRect = contentsRect().adjusted(1, 1, -1, -1);
    painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(176, 176, 176),1));
    painter.setBrush(QColor(255,255,255));
    painter.drawRect(contRect);

    painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(51,51,51),1));
    QFont font( "Calibri" );
    font.setPixelSize(14);
    painter.setFont( font );

    painter.drawText(QPointF(contRect.x() + 18, contRect.y() + 28), "Color Highlight");
}

void CascadeColorHighlightWidget::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *event)
{
   Q_UNUSED(event);
   close();
}
void CascadeColorHighlightWidget::setColors(QColor color)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::TextAntialiasing);
    QRectF contRect = contentsRect().adjusted(1, 1, -1, -1);

    int rectYPos = contRect.y() + 55;

    painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    QRectF ellipseRect = QRectF(contRect.x() + 18, rectYPos, 16, 16);

    painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter.setBrush(color);
    painter.drawEllipse(ellipseRect);
    /*After this ellipse I need to draw a line edit where user can edit anytime*/

    }
```

But by calling setcolot its not drawing the ellipse on the widget. Only the items in paintEvent worked.

Is it possible to do with painter or I need to keep widgetItems and insert in this wideget. please give some suggestions

Comment: You should paint on some `QImage`. And output this image on `paintEvent`.

Comment: You should use `setColors` only to update the color used to draw your ellipse ( assuming that color is a member of your class) and then call `QWidget::update()` that will eventually trigger a `paintEvent`. Then in your`paintEvent` method, just add the drawing of your ellipse that use your member "color" recently updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All painting work should happen in `paintEvent`. You have to keep state, and paint items accordingly. Have methods that take `QPainter` as an argument and call them from within paintEvent method, passing to them the `QPainter` object you created there.

**Example:**

In your widget header have:

```
private:
    void setColors(QColor c) { color = c; }
    void drawEllipse(QPainter & painter);
    QColor color;
    bool draw_ellipse;
```

As you can see, the setColors method only sets a color and you keep that color in a private instance variable `color`.

A new method hosts the painting job (previously in setColors):

```
void CascadeColorHighlightWidget::drawEllipse(QPainter &painter)
{
    painter.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::TextAntialiasing);
    QRectF contRect = contentsRect().adjusted(1, 1, -1, -1);

    int rectYPos = contRect.y() + 55;

    painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    QRectF ellipseRect = QRectF(contRect.x() + 18, rectYPos, 16, 16);

    painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter.setBrush(color);
    painter.drawEllipse(ellipseRect);
    /*After this ellipse I need to draw a line edit where user can edit anytime*/
}
```

The variable `color` in this line

```
painter.setBrush(color);
```

is the one you set using the `setColors` method.

The `paintEvent` method should be like:

```
void CascadeColorHighlightWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);

    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::TextAntialiasing);
    QRectF contRect = contentsRect().adjusted(1, 1, -1, -1);
    painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(176, 176, 176),1));
    painter.setBrush(QColor(255,255,255));
    painter.drawRect(contRect);

    painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(51,51,51),1));
    QFont font( "Calibri" );
    font.setPixelSize(14);
    painter.setFont( font );

    painter.drawText(QPointF(contRect.x() + 18, contRect.y() + 28), "Color Highlight");

    if(draw_ellipse)
    {
        drawEllipse(painter);
    }
}
```

At the end of it, you test `draw_ellipse` (don't forget to initialize it to `false` in the constructor) and call the `drawEllipse` method if it's `true`.

Let's draw the ellipse, for example using `QWidget`'s `mousePressEvent`:

```
void CascadeColorHighlightWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    setColors(QColor(Qt::red));
    draw_ellipse = true;
    update();
}
```

Here, you set a color, first, then set `draw_ellipse` to `true`, then (and it matters a lot) you call the [update slot](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update) of QWidget:

> [...] it schedules a paint event for processing when Qt returns to the
>   main event loop.

So the paintEvent method will be called, and your paintings updated accordingly to your class's state (`color` and `draw_ellipse` variables).

Comment: Is there any way to keep line edit beside ellipse, horizontal layout so that user can enter some text for each color. User should able to edit and change text anytime